# How can I transform the output of read.table into vector of vectors that dist will interpret correctly?

Tags: r

I am attempting to prepare a `dist` structure for use with one of the clustering libraries in R. The input is a file containing fixed-size vectors of integers. Here is a sample input, although the real input will have more than 7 columns in each row.

```
54540,22060,52234,49984,34093,16412,46758
47075,41863,26267,8577,45153,6133,31558
33741,50895,45860,49942,47074,30793,10483
24437,5884,44081,34891,41438,23705,30392
28575,50826,36723,27807,28152,31804,3303
12936,26572,5576,1758,5484,12165,19950
2086,33345,4810,15722,594,34,15562
19701,46650,38306,33724,24992,55188,53023
```

I want to read them in and have R interpret them as vectors, which should then be passed to `myfun` for the purposes of computing edit distance as the distance metric. 
However, it appears that `data` does not have the appropriate format, so `myfun` is being called with incorrect parameters.

I currently have the following code

```
library(cluster)                                                   
library(proxy)                                                     

myfun <- function(x,y) {                                           
  numDiffs <- 0;                                                   
  for (i in x) {                                                   
    if (x[i] != y[i])                                              
       numDiffs <- numDiffs + 1;                                   
  }                                                                
  return(numDiffs);                                                
}                                                                  
summary(pr_DB)                                                     

pr_DB$set_entry(FUN = myfun, names = c("myfun", "vectorham"))      
pr_DB$get_entry("MYFUN")                                           

data <- read.table("Sample.txt", header=FALSE, sep=",")            

x <- dist(x = data, method = "MYFUN")
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Error in if (x[i] != y[i]) numDiffs <- numDiffs + 1 :                     
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed                                   
Calls: dist ... .proxy_external -> do.call -> .External -> <Anonymous>
```

I have tried manually looking at `data` and it appears to be a matrix rather than a vector of vectors, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You can define `myfun` as `sum(x != y)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line `for (i in x) {`. I think you mean `for (i in seq_along(x)) {`. Anyway, try using this instead:

```
myfun <- function(x,y) sum(x != y)
```

EDIT: The following code:

```
data <- read.table(header=FALSE, sep=",", text="
54540,22060,52234,49984,34093,16412,46758
47075,41863,26267,8577,45153,6133,31558
33741,50895,45860,49942,47074,30793,10483
24437,5884,44081,34891,41438,23705,30392
28575,50826,36723,27807,28152,31804,3303
12936,26572,5576,1758,5484,12165,19950
2086,33345,4810,15722,594,34,15562
19701,46650,38306,33724,24992,55188,53023
")

library(cluster)                                                   
library(proxy)                                                     

myfun <- function(x,y) sum(x != y)

summary(pr_DB)                                                     

pr_DB$set_entry(FUN = myfun, names = c("myfun", "vectorham"))      
pr_DB$get_entry("MYFUN")                                           


x <- dist(x = data, method = "MYFUN")
```

Gives the following result to me:

```
> x
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 7            
3 7 7          
4 7 7 7        
5 7 7 7 7      
6 7 7 7 7 7    
7 7 7 7 7 7 7  
8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
> data
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7
1 54540 22060 52234 49984 34093 16412 46758
2 47075 41863 26267  8577 45153  6133 31558
3 33741 50895 45860 49942 47074 30793 10483
4 24437  5884 44081 34891 41438 23705 30392
5 28575 50826 36723 27807 28152 31804  3303
6 12936 26572  5576  1758  5484 12165 19950
7  2086 33345  4810 15722   594    34 15562
8 19701 46650 38306 33724 24992 55188 53023
```

Which I believe is correct.

Comment: On the surface, this solution gets rid of the errors. However, R still seems to think that there are more than 10 items total to be clustered  even though my small sample file only contains 10 items.

Answer (score 0):

Couple problems with this:

1. If x and y in myfun are different lengths, you could get missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed, because one will be N/A.
2. Dist doesn't take your own defined functions as far as I know. See http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/dist.html
3. What Ferdinand said about "i in x". His suggestion is good.

And a matrix really isn't any different than a vector of vectors. Just call a row vector as data[rowNum, ]. Further, a "dist structure" is just a matrix.

Comment: My vectors are fixed-length. I will try Ferdinand's answer first though.

Comment: `myfun` does get called. He is using `proxy::dist` not `stats::dist`.